# Why does modifying the child state also modify the parent state?

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

I'm having trouble finding the reason why modifying the child state also modifies the parent state even though I'm not doing anything to it.
I'm supposed to create the four child states of a "Fifteen Puzzle" in order to find least amount of steps to solve it. I'm also expected to use a Graph Search algorithm so I'd love some hints of that too. I will put below my code so you can check it. I'm only trying to create the first child at the moment since the code won't work as intended.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct State {
    int** matrix;
    int dim;
};

struct Node {
    State state;
    Node* parent;
    char action[20];
    int cost;
};

struct Position {
    int i;
    int j;
};

Position findSpace(State state) {
    Position positions = {-1, -1};
    for (int i = 0; i < state.dim; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < state.dim; j++)
        {
            if (state.matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                positions.i = i;
                positions.j = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (positions.i >= 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return positions;
}

void generateChildren(State parent, State& child1) {
    State parentCopy = parent;
    int spaceRow = findSpace(parent).i;
    int spaceColumn = findSpace(parent).j;

    if (spaceRow > 0) {
        child1 = parent;
        swap(child1.matrix[spaceRow][spaceColumn], child1.matrix[spaceRow - 1][spaceColumn]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct State {
    int** matrix;
    int dim;
};
```

This object contains pointers to the actual values. That's what `*` means in C++, in this context.

```
child1 = parent;
```

This statement copies one of these objects to the other one. Everything in the object gets copied. When done, both `parent` and `child1` have the same, identical pointers. Both of them are pointing to the same values, and that's the result you are observing.

In C++, a pointer, and what it points to, are independent of each other. Copying a pointer does not duplicate, in some form of fashion, what it points to. All you end up with is another pointer to the same underlying object or values. Using either pointer accesses the same object both of them are pointing to. This is how pointers works in C++, it's fundamental to the language.